# How to group items in ListView solely in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

To split into group i have the following code in xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvPallets" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

To actually split into groups i added `x:Name` attribute and some code in code behind file:

```
public SimulationWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _viewModel = new SimulationWindowViewModel();
    DataContext = _viewModel;

    lvPallets.Loaded += foo;
}

void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvPallets.ItemsSource);
    PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Group");
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
}
```

I would like to remove `x:Name` attribute and function `foo`. How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to define a `CollectionViewSource` in the `XAML`, simply define it in the `Resources` of the parent and use it via `x:Key`.

```
<!-- Define CollectionViewSource -->
<Parent.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupCVS" Source="{Binding Entries}">
        <!-- Group by the Property 'Group' -->
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Parent.Resources>

<!-- use the CollectionViewSource -->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupCVS}}">
```

Note: I haven't found a way to declare the `CollectionViewSource` directly in the `ListView` due it must be known before applied (-> `StaticResource`).